# Vim: :silent with makeprg

Tags: vim

I use `pylint` on .py files for `:make` in my .vimrc, although any program, `pylint` or otherwise, applies to this problem.

```
set makeprg=pylint\ --reports=n\ --output-format=parseable\ %
```

When I run `:make`, I inevitably get the annoying `Press ENTER or type command to continue` prompt. I know this can be disabled with `:silent`, but I can't prepend it to the `makeprg` variable like this, because it throws an error:

```
set makeprg=:silent "pylint\ --reports=n\ --output-format=parseable\ %"
```

If I try to have my own "Silent make command,"

```
command Smake silent make
```

The screen goes black after calling it.

How would I do it?

Comment: Why not `:silent make`?

Comment: You'll still need to redraw, per the answer; but `:silent make | redraw!` works.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `:redraw` <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>L</kbd> (or `:redraw!` to clear the screen first).

> :redraw

See [that similar topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7078538/refresh-vim-buffer), and the [Vim doc](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/various.html#CTRL-L).